# Which data type of fragment to use if I want to remove it dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am trying to get instance of the dynamically currently appearing or showing fragment as follows:

```
fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
```

but this code returns the following type android.support.v4.app.Fragment
and later I want to remove that fragment which I earlier obtains an instance of as follows:

```
mFragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
```

but this method does not accept this type android.support.v4.app.Fragment

How to solve this issue please.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `mFragmentTransaction` should be initialized with the `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()` method. Maybe you have used the `getFragmentManager()` object, witch would be incorrect in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Check your imports. If you see the following import:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

you will want to change it to the support library version to maintain consistency as follows:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your import statements and be sure you are not mixing "Support" fragments and "Native" fragments. You must use a consistent fragment and many recommend the "Support" version over the "Native" version, in which case you should be using `getSupportFragmentManager`.

Also, since you wish to remove a fragment, make sure the fragment container is not hard coded in XML. If you intend to replace or remove a fragment, then the initial fragment should be loaded dynamically by your code (you typically will load into a FrameLayout using the id as your`R.id.{frameLayoutId}`), else it will not work.